# Menu items only for registered users

Tags: drupal, menu, menuitem

How can I in Drupal define that menu item link is available only for registered users, and not for users that are not loged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure the node this menu item leads to can be accessed only by registered users. Try access control modules if there's no inbuilt mechanism that works for you. I sometimes use Content Access for that, although it's primarily for controlling access per content type. You can try Nodeaccess, which controls access per node.

Comment: how can i define that node can be accessed only by registered users? i need it both for story and for page.

Comment: Like I said: use Content Access if you want to restrict access per content type, or Nodeaccess if you wish to set per node access permissions.

Comment: a-ha those are custom modules. tnx!

Comment: ok. which one do you recommend? can you post links to modules pages?